# Making a Tactful Comparison using "as....as"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Anne is as **old** as Lucy.

The use of the word **old** here is usual because it shows that they have the same age.

Anne is as **young** as Lucy.

The use of the word **young** here is unusual because it puts special emphasis on the word **young**.

Could someone please elaborate why it's **unusual** to use the word **young** when you compare people? Thank you!

Comment: The question title says **tactful** yet "Anne is as old as Lucy" is **tactless**. One can say "Anne is the same age as Lucy".

Comment: Thank you, Weather Vane. How about if Anne and Lucy are both 50 years old?

Comment: "Anne is as old as Lucy" can be applied to young people at an age when getting older is good. But age, and the experience of age, is relative. Who is to know if saying that in the hearing of a 50-year-old does not send a bullet through their heart? Or at 40, 30?

Answer (score 2):

Using **as young as** to talk about people who *are* young isn't unusual at all.

Generally speaking, if it sounds normal to say "Anne is young" then it will also sound normal to say "Anne is as young as Lucy."

Even in a qualified context it's fine. "Anne is young *for her age*—and Lucy is just as young as Anne."

---

One reason it sounds strange to use *young* rather than *old* in some cases is because the word *old* serves a dual purpose, while *young* does not.

We can talk about a *one-year-****old*** child, but it's not idiomatic to talk about a *one-year-****young*** child. So even though the child *isn't* old (but is actually young), the adjectival phrase that describes the child's age uses the word *old*.

As such, *old* is used to quantify an objective number of years. So, when we say that *Anne is as old as Lucy*, we mean that Anne has lived the same number of years as Lucy.

But when we say that *Anne is as young as Lucy* (when we would normally call neither of them young), we get a bit tripped up because *young* isn't used in that way. Instead, it's used to ascribe a quality to someone—that of *youth*. So hearing *young* used to describe years lived sounds strange.